# Efficiency of tuple construction in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, constructor, tuples

I'm wondering about the efficiency of the `tuple` constructor vs the `list` constructor.

Here is my understanding of `list` construction. The expression `list(range(100))` probably does not immediately recognize that the `Iterable` has 100 elements, so it makes a container with some default initial capacity, and it adds elements until it is full. When full, it makes a new container with expanded capacity, copies elements over, and repeats. This continues until all the elements from the `Iterable` are exhausted.

Consider the expression `tuple(range(100))`. I assume the same mechanisms are at play because the `tuple` constructor doesn't know how large the `Iterable` is. It must create a container with some spare capacity, fill, then repeat.

The `tuple` type stores elements directly (as opposed to `list` which stores a reference to a container that houses the elements). A `tuple` also doesn't have spare capacity for appending new elements.

Since the `tuple` constructor made use of an intermediate container to house the elements, does this mean that the final step of the `tuple` constructor is to copy all the elements from the container into a proper `tuple` type with no spare capacity? If so, this would make the `tuple` constructor less efficient than the `list` constructor because the `list` probably just keeps the intermediate container used during construction. If not, does this mean that the `tuple` somehow keeps the container used in construction?

I tried to benchmark them but got no meaningful disparity.

```py
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> rng = 5000
>>> num = 5000
>>> print(timeit(stmt=f'tuple(range({rng}))', number=num))
0.444614720006939
>>> print(timeit(stmt=f'list(range({rng}))', number=num))
0.4465303409961052
```

Comment: you should not be worrying about this microoptimization- instead think do you want a mutable container (i.e. list) or a immutable one (i.e. tuple)

Comment: Aside from adding zero's to the benchmark, I don't think there's much to do here. It doesn't look like the tuple constructor is wasting time compared to the list constructor. It also doesn't look like there's something to be gained here in a common python program. (and if there is, should you be writing python code?)

Comment: With potentially tens of millions of elements, I am wondering if the tuple constructor keeps it's internal container. If so, it would mean that I would be storing a few million additional elements in memory. If not, then I am copying tens of millions of elements on the last step.

Comment: The [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/changelog.html#id83) for Python 3.8 mentions: "[bpo-33234](https://bugs.python.org/issue33234): _The list constructor will pre-size and not over-allocate when the input length is known_."

Comment: If you're so much into the internals of CPython, I suggest reading the source code from [`tupleobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/tupleobject.c) and [`listobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/listobject.c).

Comment: list(range(100)) _does_ know the length needed, as the range object implements `__len__`. But I really wouldn't expect any differences between tuple and list except that one has methods that allow it to be mutated and the other doesn't.

Comment: Don't conflate how an instantiated list or tuple behaves with how its internal constructor constructs it. Just because you can't append to a tuple doesn't mean the constructor abides by the same limitations.